# Pass gesture/touches to another UIView if top level UIView does not receive the gesture it wants to handle?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

There are a few similar questions I've found around here but none that will satisfy my requirements.

My problem is: I have a UIView set up with controls, a collection view and a few other things. Standard iOS stuff.

When the user does a two finger pan down the screen, a search bar is supposed to drop from the top and the main UIView will also go down a bit as well.

The way I'm trying to accomplish this is by having a UIView that lies at the top level and intercepts all touches and gestures. What I'd like for it to do is to ignore gestures that are not a two finger pan and pass them down as the raw inputs so the rest of the app can behave as normal.

I cannot simply add the pan gesture recognizer to the root UIView as collection views seem to block pans from going to the root.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Adding an overlay view, just to use a pan gesture, is an overkill. If you pass down all other touches from this overlay view (which is definitely possible), you will be solving the wrong problem.
Instead, you can prevent the collection view from stealing pan gesture's touches form your root view. For this, after you add the pan gesture on root view, iterate through all gestures on collection view and make them require the pan gesture to fail. In below code, assume `panDownGesture` is the two finger pan down you have added to root view.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.collectionView.gestureRecognizers) {
    [recognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:panDownGesture];
}
```

This will avoid collection view from getting any gestures when the pan gesture is detected.

**EDIT :**

Taking a cue from your comment, i checked all default gestures on a collection view, using the same loop i've shown above. It turns out, collection view already has a pan gesture with `maximumNumberOfTouches = 4294967295`, and `minimumNumberOfTouches = 1`. This is the gesture which conflicts with your pull down gesture. To avoid this, just change the `maximumNumberOfTouches` for this pan gesture to 1. You can do this with a modified version of above code :

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.collectionView.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        ((UIPanGestureRecognizer)recognizer).maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    }
    [recognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:panDownGesture];
}
```

**WARNING :** This does not allow paning the collection view with more than one finger anymore. With this code, you are in a somewhat risky territory. You are not just making a default gesture depend on something else, but are changing how it works. Hopefully, this will not affect the collection view adversly and you should be able to scroll with one finger. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as the UICollectionView starts exhibiting odd behaviour - it doesn't follow the users finger panning up and down itself.

Comment: If you set `minimumNumberOfTouches = 2` and `maximumNumberOfTouches = 2` for your `panDownGesture`, pan down will not be detected with single touch. This will avoid conflict with all other gestures on any other views. Of course 2 finger pan on the collection view itself will not work.

Comment: I tried that but I get different behaviour based on if the scrollview contents is larger than its bounds or not (seems to ignore it when the contents is less than its bounds)

Comment: @soshiki Check if the code after my **EDIT** works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "CustomUiView.h"

@implementation CustomUiView.h

-(BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    return NO;
}
@end
```

The view you do not want to interact.
create custom UIView class and use this custom view as your top view that return NO in pointInside method. Then the touch will go automatically underearth.